# Error in the reasoning?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

> Give an example of a metric space $(M,d)$, an $a\in M$ and a $R\in \mathbb{R}, R> 0$ such that
>
> $$\overline{B(a,R)} \not = \overline{B} (a,R)$$
>
> Prove in general $\overline{B(a,R)}\subseteq \overline{B} (a,R)$

I have found a counterexample, but I get stuck in the proof

#### Counterexample:

Choose $(M,d_\text{discrete})$ and $R=1$, then:

$$\overline{B(a,1)} = \{ a\} \qquad \qquad \overline{B}(a,1) = M$$

#### Proof:

Choose $x \in \overline{B(a,R)}$, then $x\in B(a,R)$ or $x\in \partial B(a,R)$ and so $x\in \overline{B}(a,R)$.

The proof seems right on first sight, but I can't seem to find why it would fail for the converse?

Let $x\in \overline B(a,R)$ then $x\in B(a,R)$ or $x\in \partial B(a,R)$. So $x\in \overline{B(a,R)}$.

I guess the proof isn't right after all?

Comment: What is $B$ here? Ball?

Comment: The open ball around $a$ with radius $R$ is $B(a,R)$.

Comment: And by $\overline{B(a, R)}$, you mean the closure of the open ball $B(a, R)$, and by $\overline{B}(a, R)$, you mean the closed ball of radius $R$ at $a$?

Comment: @BrianTung Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: when you say $x\in \overline{B}(a,R)$, then $x\in B(a,R)$ or $x\in \partial B(a,R)$ implies $x\in \overline{B(a,R)}$. This isn't entirely correct because you are making the assumption that the boundary is always in the closure.

Comment: @AnuragA But since $\partial V = \overline V \setminus V°$ then $V°\sqcup \partial V = \overline V$? (where $°$ stands for interior)

Comment: @dietervdf: OK, I was just confirming.  I just noticed that you edited $\overline{B}(a, 1) = M$ (it used to say $\{a\}$, and I was going to ask about that).

Comment: I think Anurag's point is that the boundary of the closed ball is not the same thing as that which is added by closing the open ball (especially in the case of the discrete metric).

Comment: Ok, I get that. And I see how the counterexample demonstrates this nicely. But I don't see why the topological properties as $\overline V = V°\sqcup \partial V$ don't *seem* to hold...

Comment: @dietervdf: That property does hold. Note that $\overline{B}(x,r)$ is not the closure of any given set of our interest. The upper bar is just a notation here, different from closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the upper bar in $\overline{B}(a,r)$ does not denote the closure of a set, especially not that of $B(a,r)$. So $x\in \overline{B}(a,r)$ does not imply $x\in B(a,r)$ or $x\in \partial B(a,r)$ as it would if the upper bar did denote closure. What it does imply is simply $d(a,x)\leq r$. Here $\overline{B}(a,r)$ is just a convention that could be replaced by any other notation of your preference, for instance $D(a,r)$ or $C(a,r)$, any of which could suit as a fine notation for the set $\{x\in M: d(x,a)\leq r\}$.

Comment: But $x\in \overline B(a, r)$ implies $d(x,a)\leqslant r \Rightarrow d(x,a)< r$ or $d(x,a)=r$. Where $d(x,a)<r$ translates into $x\in B(a,r)$ and $d(x,a)=r$ translates into $x\in \partial B(a,r)$.  I guess the error here is $d(x,a) = r \not \Leftrightarrow x \in \partial B(a,r)$ but this really feels strange.

Comment: @dietervdf. but that's the thing. $d(x,a)=r$ does **not** translate to $x\in \partial B(a,r)$.